# How to sort a List with grouping in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I have this class:

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    int type; // 0 = ADMIN, 1 = NON-ADMIN
}
```

Now I have a List of Employees

```
List<Employee> liste;
```

Can I sort the list in a way that all **ADMIN** employees are sorted, and appear before all `NON-ADMIN` sorted employees in the result?

Comment: I suggest you use an enum for `type` instead of magic numbers.

Comment: Could you provide the implementation of comparator. I tried this:
 java.util.Collections.sort(list, (a,b)->  
          a.name.compareTo(b.name) + (a.type - b.type)
      );

Comment: @khelwood I will use it, once I get the logic correct. I know magic numbers should be avoided.

Comment: There's a difference between "grouping and sorting the groups" and "sorted grouping and sorting the groups". Your title is about the first while your explanation is about the latter. You can only do it in one pass if you backtrack -- otherwise you can't sort inside the ADMIN and NON-ADMIN groups (only add to them).

Comment: Your comparator implementation is wrong according to what you ask in the question.

Comment: @CrazyNinja, two things: Do you know a quick way to prove that my comparator implementation is wrong. I was asked this question in interview and this was my first intution. I could not demonstrate the verity of it.Also, what should be the right implementation?

Comment: It's not that hard to see that that is wrong. The admin/non-admin would be the first sorting criteria. While ```a.type - b.type``` can return either 1 or -1, ```String::compareTo``` returns values that can be much greater or smaller, making the result of the type comparison not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a comparator, and sort first by type and then by name (assuming that's what you want).

```
java.util.Collections.sort(list, (a,b)-> 
    a.type != b.type ? a.type - b.type : a.name.compareTo(b.name);)
```

Something like that should work assuming that's actually what you want. 
`String`'s compare to

> This is the definition of lexicographic ordering. If two strings are
>   different, then either they have different characters at some index
>   that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are
>   different, or both. If they have different characters at one or more
>   index positions, let k be the smallest such index; then the string
>   whose character at position k has the smaller value, as determined by
>   using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In
>   this case, compareTo returns the difference of the two character
>   values at position k in the two string -- that is, the value:
>
> `this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)`
>
> If there is no index
>   position at which they differ, then the shorter string
>   lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo
>   returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the
>   value:
>
> `this.length()-anotherString.length()`

That's from the docs. Don't rely on compareTo returning exactly 1,0,-1. Instead just remember +,0,-. Your comparator would be wrong if the difference in length is 1 and the difference in types is -1, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a composite comparator:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getType).thenComparing(Employee::getName));
```

Comment: I like this functional implementation

Answer (score 0):

this way, non admin appears first :

```
List<Employee> temp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
while(it.hasNext()){
        Employee employee = it.next();
        if (employee.getType() == 0){
            it.remove();
            temp.add(employee);
        }
}
staff.addAll(temp);
```